# PDF rendering issue with Khmer language

Tags: android, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation

I have created a pdf with help of droidText (iText) library .

But in khmer language the text shows up broken when using the KhmerOS.ttf font.

I have temporarily solved that problem with another font Honuman.ttf but other problem is it(Honuman.ttf) cannot render all the text as per khmer.

I have used over 57 fonts trying to solve this problem but found no solution.

If knows another library or font which supports Khmer language please share the same,Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the issue of font family, it's the rendering issue and the android version you were/are using.

I think your issue should be solved with recent Android version from 4.4.4 that the render of Khmer Unicode is fine.

And I think you do not need to focus on previous version.